# Getting attribute form data from another layer

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, point-in-polygon

I’m trying to use the attributes form in QGIS 3. Most of what I’m doing is relatively simple use of combo boxes but I’ve run up against a wall.

The idea is that I’m trying to streamline how we notify people of issues on their land. The layer I’m working on is points of note, and I’d like to take the name of the owner of the land, which is stored in a separate polygon vector file.

My idea was to use the `'text edit'` widget and write an expression to default to the name of the property owner from another layer.

Comment: a spatial join? https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_spatial_joins.html

Comment: you can use the aggregate function, which is very powerful

Comment: Wonderful @eurojam that's very helpful